# How to write a NectarJS program that accepts arguments?

Tags: javascript, linux, compilation, arguments, nectarjs

Well,the question is in the title, so what i am going to do is just give you an example and hopefully someone can help!

**Note:** I am using Linux Mint 18.x

Here is what i want to be able to do:

```
#compile the javascrpit code with nectar  
nectar file.js --single -o compiledFile  
#now i want to run it with a second argument witch is an input file  
./compiledFile inputFile
```

I know that JavaScrpit itself doesn't support that kind of a ting but is there something similar in the NectarJS library/compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use process.argv like with Node (specify --env node with nectar cli, or require("process") in std env)

a short example :

```
for(var i = 0; i < process.argv.length; i++)
{
  console.log(process.argv[i]);
}
```